# Delete lines using RegEx

Tags: notepad++, regex, grep

I have a situation mentioned below. I need the keep the sentences/lines starting with {digits} and delete rest of the lines. I tried this but not working. Find: [^({\d{1,2}}.+?\r)] Replace:$1
The list numbers are enclosed in curly braces

1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
2. This is yet another line.
3. This line is continuous with point 2.

Some sentences in this para.

1. This is item number one
2. This is another line
3. This is yet another line.

I want to delete all the sentences, paragraphs except the numbered lists.

I have text matter pasted in Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h+\d+.+\R(*SKIP)(*F)|.+\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    \h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    \d+             # 1 or more digits
    .+              # 1 or more any character
    \R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    (*SKIP)(*F)     # skip previous match and declare a fail
  |               # OR
    .+              # 1 or more any character
    \R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Replacement:**

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Hello Toto
Thanks so much for the reply. For some reason my whole data is getting deleted.
This is the code I am using   ^\h+\d+.+\R(*SKIP)(*F)|.+\R

Comment: @Shahid: Have you **un**checked `. matches newline`?

Comment: It worked. I was making a mistake in text. Thanks so much. I have one more question which I am putting as a new post. I need help on that one too. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Shahid: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)